# Find a column name and retaining certain string in that entire column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I would like to format the "status" column in a csv and retain the string inside single quotation adjoining comma ('sometext',)

Example:

**Input**
[image]

as in row2&3 - if more than one values are found in any column values then it should be concatenated with a pipe symbol(|)Ex. Phone|Charger

Expected output should get pasted in same status column like below

[image]

My attempt (not working):

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("test projects.csv") 
scol = df.columns.get_loc("Status") 
statusRegex = re.
compile("'\t',"?"'\t',") mo = statusRegex.search (scol.column)
```

Comment: your question is very hard to read - I can't even edit it properly. Can you try and make it clearer?

Comment: *"Requesting Python code to..."* - that's not how this site works... Please take the [tour], read about [ask] and provide a [mre]

Comment: Hi sharath, I understand what you are asking but your question is too broad and very poorly formatted. images for excel are not ideal. What are you using to access the excel spreadsheet? which spreadsheet is it on? what format is the excel? xls, xlsx, etc...You might be better off searching for some questions about working with excl in python. since you really have two questions here. How do I work with excel data in python and how do I do this.

Comment: @Pygirl: Thank you for the below answer I get some idea i will try and see how to apply in my case.

Comment: @ak_slick: I'm using xlrd and pandas. Its in sheet1 and csv format. import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("test projects.csv")
scol = df.columns.get_loc("Status")  statusRegex = re.compile("'*\t*',"?"'*\t*',")
mo = statusRegex.search (scol.column) I tried something like this

Comment: @sharathkumar I added some extra code to my solution to help with your reading in the file. please accept an answer if this works for you. It should be very close to what you need.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help and suggestions. Please find the final working codes.

df = pd.read_csv('test projects.csv')

rows = len(df['input'])

def get_values(value):

```
m = re.findall("'(.+?)'",value)

word = ""

for mm in m:

    if 'value' not in str(mm):
        if 'autolabel_strategy' not in str(mm):
            if 'String Matching' not in str(mm):
              word += mm + "|"
return str(word).rsplit('|',1)[0]
```

al_lst =[]

ans_lst = []

for r in range(rows):

```
auto_label = df['autolabeledValues'][r]
answers = df['answers'][r]

al = get_values(auto_label)
ans = get_values(answers)
al_lst.append(al)
ans_lst.append(ans)
```

df['a'] = al_lst

df['b'] = ans_lst

df.to_csv("Output.csv",index=False)

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have df as :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[{'a':'1', 'b': '4'}]], [[{'a':'1', 'b': '2'}, {'a':'3', 'b': '5'}]]], columns=['pr'])
```

---

**df:**

```
     pr
0   [{'a': '1', 'b': '4'}]
1   [{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, {'a': '3', 'b': '5'}]
```

---

```
df['comb'] = df.pr.apply(lambda x: '|'.join([i['a'] for i in x]))
```

---

**df:**

```
    pr                                              comb
0   [{'a': '1', 'b': '4'}]                          1
1   [{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, {'a': '3', 'b': '5'}]    1|3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# simplified mock data
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    value=[23432] * 3,
    Status=[
        [{'product.type': 'Laptop'}],
        [{'product.type': 'Laptop'}, {'product.type': 'Charger'}],
        [{'product.type': 'TV'}, {'product.type': 'Remote'}]
    ]
))

# make a method to do the desired formatting / extration of data
def da_piper(cell):
    """extracts product.type and concatenates with a pipe"""
    vals = [_['product.type'] for _ in cell]  # get only the product.type values
    return '|'.join(vals)  # join them with a pipe

# save to desired column
df['output'] = df['Status'].apply(da_piper)  # apply the method to the Status col
```

Additional help: You do not need to use read_excel since csv is not an excel format. It is comma separated values which is a standard format. in this case you can just do this:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# make a method to do the desired formatting / extration of data
def da_piper(cell):
    """extracts product.type and concatenates with a pipe"""
    vals = [_['product.type'] for _ in cell]  # get only the product.type values
    return '|'.join(vals)  # join them with a pipe
    
# read csv to dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("test projects.csv")

# apply method and save to desired column
df['Status'] = df['Status'].apply(da_piper)  # apply the method to the Status col
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is helpful in reading each cell value and replacing with desired output. I will try to use this logic. Thanks again

Comment: @sharathkumar Please select it as the answer to your question if it meets your needs. Glad you found it helpful.